# how to convert the following code into list comprehensions

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the code using for loop, i want the code into list comprehension.

```
mainLst = [[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]
lst2 = [[],[],[],[]]
const = 0
for i in range(4):
    k = const
    for j in range(4):
        lst2[const].append(mainLst[k][0])
        k += 1
    const += 1
print(lst2)
```

Expecting the above code into list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform just a loop part and still use `mainLst` variable, then it will look like:

```py
mainLst = [[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]
lst2 = [[mainLst[j + k][0] for k in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
print(lst2)

# or if you still want to have initialized lst2 array, then:

lst2 = [[],[],[],[]]
[lst2[j].extend([mainLst[j + k][0] for k in range(4)]) for j in range(4)]
print(lst2)
```

Both output the same:

```sh
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without creating other variables like `k` and `const`

```py
lst2 = [[i for i in range(j, j + 4)] for j in range(2, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `itemgetter` with `slice` to get slices of sublists from the list and `chain.from_iterable` to merge sublists into one list:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

mainLst = [[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]

[list(chain.from_iterable(itemgetter(slice(i, i + 4))(mainLst))) for i in range(4)]
# [[2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```